# Allow Member to delete account, but not edit?

Tags: members, member-details

I've created a Member Group and want members in that group to be able to delete their own account. I've edited the Member Group Settings to set `Can delete own account - deletes all posts, entries, and comments as well` to "Yes", but didn't see anything in the Control Panel that would allow the member to delete his/her account. I then set `Can access MEMBERS section` to "Yes", but that gave the member access to ALL members, which is not what I want.

How does a member delete his/her account? And what settings does the Member Group need to have?

Also, I don't want the Member to be able to edit their Member details. When a user clicks on their screen name (left of the "logout" link on the top right of CP), they are taken to a "My Account" page where the member can edit profile, avatar, etc. I want to prevent access to any of that. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1: Where should a member delete his or her account?

This is explained in the user guide: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/members/member_groups_edit.html

### Can delete own account - deletes all posts, entries, and comments as well

Determines whether a member of the group can delete their own account.
**If enabled, members of this group will be able to delete their own account through their front-end member control panel.**

So there it is: the setting can be used via the *front-end* member control panel.

---

Question 2:
How can I make sure a member cannot edit account details?

You should take a look at the member templates: check the "themes" folder --> "profile themes". Use something like `{if member_group == "4"}`  and show a message "You're not authorised to see this page" (or something like that) instead of the form.